# refresh filter text bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

So i have an input element with filter and list. After i choose any list item,it changes name of default text written in the input into the text written in the chosen list item.I want to refresh the default text written in the input after i press some button. 
I tried doing it using innerHTML and .text(),but it failed.

HTML

```
<div class="filter">
   <input type="text" class="region formClear" id="myInput" 
      onkeyup="myFunction()" value="regions" title="Type in a name">
          <ul id="myUL">
            <li><a class="rgn" href="#">region1</a></li>
            <li><a class="rgn" href="#">region2</a></li>
          </ul>
</div>
<button onclick="defaultChange()">refresh</button>
```

Javascript

```
function defaultChange(){
    //$('#myInput').text("regions");
    $('#myInput').innerHTML="regions";
}
```

Comment: You can't mix jQuery objects and standard JS like that.

Comment: `$('#myInput').val("regions")`

Comment: @Aluan Haddad thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `.val()` function for this:

```
function defaultChange(){
    $('#myInput').val("regions");
}
```

An `input` doesn't have any HTML value, it's a replaced element, so you need to set its value.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use jQuery `val()` function to get the value of input like

```
$('#myInput').val("regions")
```

*`innerHTML` is used to change the inner html of the element.*

***Stack Snippet***

```js
function defaultChange() {
  $('#myInput').val("regions");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <input type="text" class="region formClear" id="myInput" onkeyup="" value="regions1" title="Type in a name">
</div>
<button onclick="defaultChange()">refresh</button>
```